# Show Tax Amount but don't include in SubTotal & Grand Total

Tags: templates, magento-1.9, checkout, tax, system-configuration

I need help regarding **Magento 1.9.2**, I want to show the Tax amount but don't want to include in **SubTotal** and in **GrandTotal** amount.

i have already play around with Tax Settings **admin-->System-->Configuration-->Sales-->Tax-->Shopping Cart Display Settings**

But still no Result. I have also visited similar question's post on this Forum or any other forums but all in vain.

Please have look at the image below

[image: Image for More Clarification]

Anyone, please help to purpose any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what you want to achieve. Grand total = Subtotal + Tax. this is common logic.

but whatever. Answer to your question is:

You may manipulate renderer templates for totals.
Located at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout
(or in the Theme app/design/frontend/*Your Theme*/*Path*/template/tax/checkout)

You can simply use this getter `$this->getTotal()->getValueExclTax()` in renderer template `../template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`
to get Grandtotal without Tax.

Comment: that's why i have attached the image together for your better understanding

Comment: I understood, but making grandtotal same as subtotal if tax is there, is simply unlogical :). Anyway you can do this, if you check templates in suggested folder. Please don't forget to accept and upvote, if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.

Yes, understand but the system is develop like that.So have to follow up accordingly.

Comment: see updated answer. if your checkout is based on default theme it will work just fine.

Comment: i have Solve the issue already by using the same approach (getValueExclTax()) annd thanks for reply.

Comment: And sorry i can't upvote because my reputation is below 15...lol

you can help me to Upvote the Question i post then only i will be able to upvote for you. btw i have post another question please have look as well.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213416/shopping-cart-price-rule-magneto-1-9-2/213417#213417

thanks

Comment: you still may accept the answer, if it was helpful. this is even better than upvote

Comment: :) by accepting an answer I meant clicking on ✓ on the left side of the answer)))

Comment: already bro, please have a look on my 2nd question mentioned in the comments. Thanks

Comment: how to achieve same in order emails